# get the value of a field of nodes inside an extra field

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have listed the node articles in the teaser mode. I have added an extra field, which is a select field (Using form API).

For more explanation, this is what I have done :

1. Define a form with form API

> ```
> function article_flag_term_form($form, &$form_state) {
>     $form['term_flag'] = array(
>         '#type' => 'select',
>         '#options' => custom_selectbox_contents(7), // function to get the items of the vocabulary having the id : 7
>         '#ajax' => array(
>             'callback' => '_term_flag_change'
>         )
>     );
>     return $form;
> }
> ```

I added this form as an extra field with `hook_field_extra_fields`, so I can see this simple form in each node listed in teaser mode :

```
function MY_MODULE_field_extra_fields() {

    $extra['node']['article']['display'] = array(
        'flag_form' => array(
           'label' => t('flag form'),
           'description' => t('Flag form addded to Node Content'),
           'weight' => 10,
        )
    );

    return $extra;
}
```

And the idea was to allow users to change the value of this vocabulary of each article.

The question is how can I put the default value of this select box with the correct value of the vocabulary item of each article.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post the code that you're using in `hook_field_extra_fields` ? thanks

Comment: yes sure,
I updated now the post, but the problem is not in the extra field itself, the problem is how can I update and save the new value of the taxonomy term "flag" with the chosen by the user, so first of all I need to show up in the form added by hook_field_extra_fields, the default value of this taxonomy term!

Comment: This code doesn't look like you're adding a form to the node, just a simple field to display. To add your form, you should have something like `$extra['node']['article']['form'] = array("flag_term" => ...)` according to the api: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7

Comment: No this is work for me and it displays the select field mentioned in every listed node,
anyway this is a simple think to complete this task,
So if you have another idea I will be very thankfull,

The idea is like I said in the post, is to allow front-end user to change this field.
How can I proceed to do this !